# Event Handling doesnot work for the following wxpython code.No error after I Run it.The Frame/buttons displayed

Tags: event-handling, wxpython

nO ERROR AT run TIME.NO OTHER DEF WORKS OTHER THAN *INIT*

```
import wx
import os
from spectral import *

class Frame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self, title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=(1000,70),style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX|wx.CLOSE_BOX|wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.SYSTEM_MENU|wx.CAPTION|wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
    panel=wx.Panel(self,-1)
    self.button=wx.Button(panel,label="Open",pos=(0,0),size=(50,30))
    self.button1=wx.Button(panel,label="Save",pos=(51,0),size=(50,30))
    self.button2=wx.Button(panel,label="ROI",pos=(102,0),size=(50,30))
    self.button3=wx.Button(panel,label="Tone",pos=(153,0),size=(50,30))
    self.slider=wx.Slider(panel,pos=(204,0))
    self.button4=wx.Button(panel,label="Header",pos=(305,0),size=(50,30))
    self.SetBackgroundColour((11, 11, 11))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.onMouseOver)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.onMouseLeave)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonClick,self.button)
    self.filename=""


def OnButtonClick(self,event):
    dlg=wx.FileDialog(self,message="Choose a file", defaultDir="",defaultFile="", wildcard="*.*", style=wx.OPEN)
    if dlg.ShowModal==wx.ID_OK:
        dlg.Destroy()
def onMouseOver(self, event):
    self.SetBackgroundColor((179, 179, 179))
    self.Refresh()
def onMouseLeave(self, event):
    self.SetBackgroundColor((11, 11, 11))
    self.Refresh()


def OnClose(self, event):
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, 
        "Do you really want to close BBvw ?",
        "Confirm Exit", wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
    result = dlg.ShowModal()
    dlg.Destroy()
    if result == wx.ID_OK:
        self.Destroy()

 app = wx.App(redirect=True)
 top = Frame("BBvw")
  top.Show()
 app.MainLoop()
```

nO ERROR AT run TIME.NO OTHER DEF WORKS OTHER THAN INIT.I think I am missing something obvious.'int' not callable error when buttons are clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OnButtonClick() method is getting called, but you're not calling ShowModal correctly. You need to put the parentheses on it: ShowModal()

Then that will work. The OnClose() works for me. The Mouse ones don't, but I'm not sure why. You should ask about those on the wxPython mailing list.